# What do I need to run xCode app on iPhone device for my own personal use: no AppStore, no commerce, not public - just personal?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I wonder, what do I need to have my xCode app on iPhone device?

For example, I built CoolGuitarTuner app which I want to use myself and maybe share it with a couple of friends.

Can I just somehow copy it on my iPhone for my own private use without any registrations or payments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still need a $99 developer account. That should be all you need, regardless of whether or not you list any apps for sale. Or you could jailbreak.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more, what this developer account will allow me technically?

Comment: You need a developer account in order to develop an app and put it on your device. It's also required for submitting to the AppStore. You also get access to some other things on developers.apple.com, like betas and pre-release software. Without the $99 account, the only way you can get non-AppStore apps on your device is to Jailbraeak.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through  [iPhone Test Application](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/test.html)

And [This Blog](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices) gives your detailed information about how to deploy application on your device

Hope this will help you out.